# duplicate rows consolidation sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to consolidate duplicate rows group by 2 columns. Need to merge/overwrite data from old T_ID row values to most recent T_ID row. How do I order by rows by T_ID column in a group of COL1 and COL2? This following select statement displays all rows with and without duplicates. I need to return only rows with duplicates so that I am planning to write a CURSOR to merge/overwrite old rows data content to most recent T_ID row. Any suggestions?

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL2, COL3  ORDER BY COL2,COL3) AS RN
FROM TABLE_1 t
where ( LEN(ISNULL(t.COL2,'')) <> 0) and t.COL3 is not null 

)
SELECT *
FROM CTE;
```

Here is the format.

```
T_ID  COL2 COL3 col4 col5 col6 col7
10    990   123            1     
40    990   123  1         1    1    
30    991   124  2    2    2    2    
33    991   124  3         1    4
```

After merge

```
T_ID  COL2 COL3 col4 col5 col6 col7
40    990   123  1         1    1    
33    991   124  2    2    2    2
```

Comment: What if COL2 & COL3 had more than two rows with the same values?

Comment: merge/update all data to most recent T_ID row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I order by rows by T_ID column in a group of COL1 and COL2?

Assuming within partition of COL2 and COL3 as COL1 doesn't exist in your example (maybe typo mistake), in that case the `order by` goes as follows:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL2, COL3  ORDER BY T_ID) AS RN
```

And following query can get the result same as expected merge result, you can use it in further logical DELETE or UPDATE query:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL2, COL3  ORDER BY T_ID DESC) AS RN
FROM TABLE_1 t
where ( LEN(ISNULL(t.COL2,'')) <> 0) and t.COL3 is not null 

)
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1;

``
```

Comment: order by T_ID works. Is it possible to exclude rows with no duplicates?

Comment: tried to use RN > 1 but it eliminates duplicate row(first row) if there are 2 rows. trying to get all duplicate rows.

Comment: Consider `RN = 1` is always unique values based defined partition (COL2 and COL3). Yes, you must get only duplicates when you use `RN>1`. Also, this gets same result and it's optimal `not RN = 1`